# magento found valid path image in new page

Tags: magento

i have created a new page using CMS->Page->Add New Page, My page title is `About Us` and the url key is `about-us`, in content i have insert this

```
 {{block type="core/template" template="content/about-us.phtml"}}
```

this my code from about-us.phtml

```
 <div>
    <img src="skin/frontend/default/blank/images/mypic.jpg"/> 
 </div>
```

my problem is image (mypic.jpg) doesnt show in about us page, please help me..

thx..

Answer (score 2):

you should have to use `getSkinUrl` function to work with your current skin of front end and grep image from it.

```
<div>      
   <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/mypic.jpg');?>"/> 
 </div>
```

hope this will sure help you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate Solution:

```
<img src="{{skin url='images/yopur-image.png'}}" alt="" />
```

Image File Location is:-
\magento\skin\frontend\default\default\images